# Access vba: listbox additem multicolumn truncating on comma

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox with two colunms, but the first is hidden that adds values onto a listbox in the same manner. I am noticing that the list box is truncating the string in the second column.

This is my code thus far where cmbPart is the combobox and lstPart is the listbox.

```
Me.lstPart.AddItem (CStr(Me.cmbPart.Value) & " ;" & CStr(Me.cmbPart.Column(1, Me.cmbPart.ListIndex)))
```

I notice that that when there is a comma (,) in the string it stops displaying the rest from `Me.cmbPart.Column(1, Me.cmbPart.ListIndex)`.

How can I stop the behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aperently strings with commas in to be added to a multicolunm listbox bust be enclosed in single quotes.

```
Me.lstPart.AddItem (CStr(Me.cmbPart.Value) & " ;" & CStr("'" & Me.cmbPart.Column(1, Me.cmbPart.ListIndex)) & "'")
```

Comment: jeez, i didn't knw that. Thanks for such simple, yet super fix.